# Data points in cluster do not show up

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

So, I have this clustering algorithm and although everything is running with no error popping up and from my console it seems that the data points are being generated but do not show up in the graph. The only thing I can see is the centroids.

Disclaimer. I use the first 100 rows for testing only since, my computer is not the best and it takes a long time to process the whole dataframe.

```
df1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

df1=df1.replace('(null)',np.nan)

df1=df1.dropna(axis=0)

df1=df1.iloc[0:100] 

X=np.array(df1)

clf= KMeans(n_clusters=4)

clf.fit(X)

centroids= clf.cluster_centers_
labels=clf.labels_

colors=['green','red','orange','black']

for i in range(len(X)):
    plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1],colors[labels[i]],markersize=10)
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], marker='x',s=10)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What specifically is your error? Edit your question to add the error message in a clear and unambiguous manor.

Comment: Hello! So basically I do not get an error message the code is able to run without braking. But in the final result I do not see neither the datapoints or the clusters. So basically I have a graph with just the centroids in it.

Comment: Try using `scatter` consistently. Also, try to plot an entire cluster at a time.

Comment: Using `plt.plot` will by default give you a line with no markers. Plotting a single data point (i.e. `(X[i][0], X[i][1])`, one x and one y coordinate) thus creates no marker but a line...for a single point, which is not visible. Instead of looping over each point use a single call to `plt.plot`, with or without a marker of your choosing.